# html5 capture image from ipad camera

Tags: html, ipad, safari, camera, capture

Use input file tag for capture image from ipad camera.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

On Safari - back screen, on Chrome - work.

What problem with safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you should know that the camera API is new and not available for all browsers. Here you can see, if it's available for the specific browsers. You also will see that Safari doesn't support it. Only a few supports it like : GC, FF, Opera, GC for Android and Android Browser.

[Supporting Camera](http://caniuse.com/#search=capture)